# btrfs ref and backpointer mismatch, ERROR in extent allocation tree

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, luks

I have an encrypted LUKS partition, with btrfs for backups on it.

Kernel panic happened while system was mounted and performing receive/send operations during backup.

After restart no problem with LUKS itself, but on btrfs was found some errors and warnings:

**`btrfs ch -p /dev/mapper/bckp`**

`Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/mapper/bckp
UUID: 4b793176-530a-4a82-b156-3363db035760
[1/7] checking root items                      (0:01:24 elapsed, 5200849 items checked)
ref mismatch on [2351455076352 16384] extent item 0, found 1sed, 995581 items checked)
tree backref 2351455076352 parent 6690 root 6690 not found in extent tree
backpointer mismatch on [2351455076352 16384]
[2/7] checking extents                         (0:04:33 elapsed, 997158 items checked)
ERROR: errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
[3/7] checking free space cache                (0:00:30 elapsed, 4870 items checked)
[4/7] checking fs roots                        (0:09:36 elapsed, 724856 items checked)
[5/7] checking csums (without verifying data)  (0:00:42 elapsed, 1691026 items checked)
[6/7] checking root refs                       (0:00:00 elapsed, 223 items checked)
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 3669056704512 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 3565923444
total tree bytes: 16333701120
total fs tree bytes: 11922030592
total extent tree bytes: 561364992
btree space waste bytes: 2285778795
file data blocks allocated: 49969135439872
 referenced 5223974543360`

I run it with another superblock or with backup of root tree like:

**`btrfs ch -p -s 1 /dev/mapper/bckp`**

**`btrfs ch -p -b /dev/mapper/bckp`**

But with exactly same result and figures. I didn't run the repair option because it is marked as dangerous.

*Are these errors reparable? How can I save the filesystem?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks Emmanuel Rosa for your comment, you've pointed me to the right direction.**

After i run scrub on a mounted volume
`btrfs sc start -Bd /dev/mapper/bckp`

I've got this result:
`scrub device /dev/mapper/bckp (id 1) done
        scrub started at Thu Sep 12 13:28:38 2019 and finished after 05:12:29
        total bytes scrubbed: 3.02TiB with 0 errors`

No errors or warnings in logs.

So I again run btrfs check and finally got clean output:
`bf ch -p /dev/mapper/bckp 
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/mapper/bckp
UUID: 4b793176-530a-4a82-b156-3363db035760
[1/7] checking root items                      (0:01:27 elapsed, 5102746 items checked)
[2/7] checking extents                         (0:04:15 elapsed, 969366 items checked)
[3/7] checking free space cache                (0:00:32 elapsed, 4871 items checked)
[4/7] checking fs roots                        (0:09:14 elapsed, 720718 items checked)ked)
[5/7] checking csums (without verifying data)  (0:00:29 elapsed, 1557593 items checked)
[6/7] checking root refs                       (0:00:00 elapsed, 222 items checked)
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 3308474904576 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 3214237436
total tree bytes: 15878373376
total fs tree bytes: 11854004224
total extent tree bytes: 553287680
btree space waste bytes: 2253478467
file data blocks allocated: 49609008967680
 referenced 4863848071168`

My software is:
`btrfs version`
btrfs-progs v4.19

`uname -rom`
4.19.57-gentoo x86_64 GNU/Linux`

***So FS is clean and usable again without any warnings, thank you for helping me.***